# Add text label to WPF Bing Maps

Tags: wpf-controls, bing-maps

Is it possible to add text to specified location (lat/long) in WPF bing maps?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, c# code-behind I'll assume?

```
// I just created a Location object from the mouseclick but you can replace labelLocation with anything
Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location labelLocation = myMap.ViewportPointToLocation(mousePosition);

// Create a label
Label customLabel = new Label();
customLabel.Content = "Text here";
// With map layers we can add WPF children to lat long (WPF Location obj) on the map.
MapLayer labelLayer = new MapLayer();
labelLayer.AddChild(customLabel, labelLocation );
myMap.Children.Add(labelLayer);
```